# How do I get more satellites?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I received one satellite from a resource pod, but it soon degraded and fell from the sky. Now I can't figure out how to replace it or get more. What do I need to do to get more satellites?

Answer (score 5):

There are several technologies that will offer you more satellites.  A few of them are:

- Ecology gives you the Miasmic Repulsor, which does exactly what it says.
- Orbital Networks gives you the Lasercom Satellite
- Geoscaping has the Orbital Fabricator

And so on.  You build them just like other units, and can launch them anywhere you have Orbital Coverage.  They work sort of like limited area buffs, and will improve a certain aspect for a period of time.